# Facebook Messenger Bot giving unwanted default response message

Tags: facebook, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot, chatterbot

I'm following this [tutorial](https://blog.hartleybrody.com/fb-messenger-bot/) to set up a Facebook messenger bot with a ChatterBot backend. Everything works fine except that I see an additional, default response in the conversation. After Each. And. Every. Sentence. :(

[image]

The `>> Hi` is a response I have generated. The issue I'm facing is that I don't know from where the `How can I be of help? Please state what you desire to do` message comes from?

I have switched off Instant Replies in `Facebook > Settings > Messaging > Send Instant Replies to anyone who messages your Page` = `No`

Comment: Have you tried disabling chatterbot?

Comment: @amuramoto Sorry the delay in replying. Just back from holidays. I want to disable the default response and make sure only responses generated by ChatterBot are displayed. And yes, after disabling ChatterBot, I still get to see that "How can I be of help" message

Comment: Do you have a link to your code? If it's being sent after every incoming message I think it must originate somewhere in your code or in chatterbot, so since it still shows when you disable chatterbot, your code would be the next thing to look at.